# Word Count in C

Tags: c, if-statement, substring, c-strings, counting

I have a word count program in C that excludes special characters and number digits:

```c
int main(){
    char str[100];
    int i, j = 0;
    int len;
    char choice;
    
    do {
        printf("Enter String: ");
        fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);

        len = strlen(str);

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if((str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') || 
              (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')) //checks if its upper or lowercase {
                if (str[i] != ' ' && (str[i + 1] == ' ' || str[i + 1] == '\0'))//checks if the current character is a space and also the end of the string{
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }

        printf("Word count: %d\n", j);

        printf ("Try again?(Y/N): ");
        scanf (" %c", &choice);    
     
        getchar ();//use to clear input buffer
    } while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');

    return 0;  
}
```

But it doesn't count the first string after a whitespace, and seems to get a bit messy as I go on the loop.

I tried changing the values of the array, the loop, and also tried to ask AI what I've missed, but the suggestions didn't really work.

output:

```
Enter String: i
Word count: 0
Try again? (Y/N): Y
Enter String: i have 3 Apples
Word count: 2
Try again? (Y/N): Y
Enter String: hello WORLD
Word count: 3
Try again? (Y/N): hello world
```

Comment: Few unrelated comments: Mixing `fgets`, `scanf` and `getchar` is a bad idea. Also use `isalpha()`  and `isspace()` standard functions instead of your checks.

Comment: `str[i] != ' '` is always true, you can't get there if the character is not a letter. I would suggest stepping through the code in a debugger to see where it is going wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, **and results** as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Roshina De Jesus You are not resetting the variable j in the do-while loop.

Comment: *"it doesn't count the first string after a whitespace"*. Work with a state machine – you are either parsing a word or parsing a space. Begin in the 'space' state and count at the *beginning* of each word, i.e. when the state changes from 'space' to 'word'.

Comment: You also have `isalpha()` and `isspace()` etc available to use. Aside: rename the variable `j` as `wordcount`.

Comment: The `//...{` in several places makes the `{` part of the comment; it has no effect on control flow, (and certainly won't compile.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function `fgets` can append the new line character '\n' to the entered string.

You should either remove it for example like

```
str[strcspn( str, "\n" )] = '\0';
```

or take into account in your if statements.

Otherwise as a result you have for example

```
Enter String: i
Word count: 0
```

though according to your description the word count should be equal to `1`.

Secondly you are not resetting to zero the variable `j` within the do-while loop.

This expression

```
str[i] != ' '
```

in the inner if statement always evaluates to logical true. So its presence in the if statement is redundant.

Also it will be much better to use standard function `isalpha` instead of comparing characters with symbols. Also the tab character `'\t'` and also some non-alpha characters can separate words as written in your description of the task but you have ignored that. According to your approach this string `"one,two,three"` contains one word.

Comment: "much better to use standard function isalpa" --> yes, but then `isalpha()` needs to get `unsigned char` values and not `char` ones, that may be negative.